# Как сделать на vbulletin 3.8.6 автора и сообщения сбоку (рядом)?

Tags: php

Добрый день всем мастерам. Помогите решить проблему. Хочу сделать форум. Пока ограничиваюсь vbulletinom 3.8.6. Но тут проблема: сообщения, оставленные пользователями, стоят под их аватаром. А мне нужно, чтобы они стояли боком друг к другу (почти во всех vbulletin форумах это так). С помощью стилей не смог. Какой скрипт нужно изменить?
Kto nibud v kurse???

Comment: @Rajabov, используйте, пожалуйста, кириллицу.

Comment: Оказывается что это возможно в настройках форума